# TestNG handling external system dependency, clarification needed

Tags: java, junit, testng

What changes do i need to make to the following please?

I'd like make sure that `testInsert` method to only run when `testInternalAccess` passes and `testInternalAccess` not count as a failure.

```
@Test
public void testInternalAccess() {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://internalpage");
        InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail();
    }
}

@Test(groups = "database", dependsOnMethods = "testInternalAccess")
public void testInsert() {
  // some code
}
```

In the above example:

1. `testInternalAccess` runs, fails and being reported as a failed test
2. `testInsert` runs and fails

Or, using creator's of TestNG example

```
@Test
public serverStartedOk() {}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = { "serverStartedOk" })
public method1() {}
```

**How will `method1` know whether server actually started ok? How will `serverstartedOk` communicate to the world it's state?**

Comment: remove groups argument and try, everything seems to be fyn!

Comment: @Patton Does not work. Also `testInternalAccess` should not be treated as test (that fails and being reported as failed)

Comment: you mean to say that you want to run testinternalAcecess before you run testInsert? Irrespective of whether testInternalAccess passes or fails testInsert should run? Basically, If the parent test fails then the child test does't run/execute. In the other later example, the method serverStartedOk() will be run by TestNG framework and hence it knows whether the test failed or passed! Based on the status of the test execution the framework will decide whether to run further tests or not

Comment: Ultimately, i'd like for `testinternalAcecess` to be ran before all other methods (possibly in `setUp()`). I tried that (with @Before annotation). Here is what i see: `testinternalAcecess` runs and fails (due to fail()). Following that other tests run and fail (due to me not being on VPN right now)

Comment: I suggest you to use `@BeforeSuite` if you wish to run this method before you run all testng tests or use `@BeforeClass` if you wish to run tests available only in this class or `@BeforeGroups` in cases where you wish to run the test before certain groups run.

Comment: Hmm .. better. I get what i want when running from IDE (IntelliJ Idea), but when running from Maven, tests still fail. Should there be anything special in my pom?

Comment: use `@BeforeSuite(alwaysRun=true)` and try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion we had above, following is the brief summary.

As you wish to run the method `testinternalAcecess` before you run all the tests in the class use `@BeforeClass`

```
@BeforeSuite
public void testInternalAccess() {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://internalpage");
        InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        fail();
    }
}
```

The method runs only once and before all tests run in the suite! And you test method would be some thing as below

```
@Test(groups = "database")
public void testInsert() {
  // some code
}
```

Bingo and this would work!